# How to introduce Azure Blob data to C# ASP website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Originally I've made a website that can retrieve data from Azure SqlDB, but the requirement has changed, my website is expected to read those Blob JSON, also, those JSON files are stored in different Azure folders.

Know nothing about JavaScript

Comment: Quite a broad question - please look at some documentation & examples here: https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/resources/samples/storage-blob-dotnet-getting-started/

Comment: This is the [Net API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet) for storage.And this is for [JavaScriot](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js#azure-storage-sdk-v10-for-javascript). Are these what you want?

Comment: @GeorgeChen nope :(

Comment: So the API in the like isn't what you want,right?